# When to use form submit instead of simple links?

Tags: html

Is it better to use:

```
<form class="delete" action="/post/delete/id/1234.html" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="delete this post"/>
</form>
```

...instead of:

```
<a class="delete" href="/post/delete/id/1234.html">delete this post</a>
```

...when there is need to modify something in database? Like when adding, updating, deleting and voting? Also for logout action (which in my application is saving timestamps when the action is taken), etc.?

Comment: For logout, you probably don't need to pass any values in. Just unset the session/clear cookies and save the timestamp.

Comment: where are the parameters being passed? how you will know which post to delete?

Comment: @FahimParkar from form action. But it doesn't matter. The question is: is it better to use forms instead of links when the action behind "click" is modifying the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GET`, you have potential for accidental or malicious actions. Consider this:

```
<img src="http://yourdomain.com/post/delete/id/1234.html">
```

If a user views this "image" (on any website) and they have delete permissions, it will send a request to that page and delete the post. Yes you can check the referer and such things, but it is an issue that is better avoided. For this reason, I also prefer `POST` for logouts as well.

The only time you should use `GET` is to request something for viewing, not deleting, editing, or adding data.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form class="delete" action="/post/delete/id/1234.html" method="POST">
    <input type="submit value="delete this post"/>
</form>
```

About code will generate `HTTP Post`

```
<a class="delete" href="/post/delete/id/1234.html">delete this post</a>
```

Above code will generate `HTTP Get`. ***You should not use `Get` to update/delete record.*** In other words, you should not use above hyperlink to delete a record.

### HTTP Verb

Here are the explanation of HTTP Verb from [ASP.NET MVC 4 and the Web API](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430249773) book

GET - Get a specific task, identified by the URI

PUT - Replace or create the single task identified by the URI

POST - Create a new subordinate under the task identified by the URI

DELETE - Delete the tasks identified by the URI

Answer (score 2):

Well, per [the HTTP spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), POST (in this case, your form submission) is for changing data and GET (in this case, your link) is for retrieving data.  So you should use POST to delete things, and links should only be used to retrieve things.  If nothing else, this makes it slightly harder for your end users to edit the URL to delete things that they shouldn't.  But really, it's just "right" to use POST for anything that will change your data.

**EDIT:** including some text from above link:

> **GET**
>   Requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have no other effect.

Answer (score 1):

For this context it doesn't mather.

It mather when you have form items (text box, checkbox) or if you want to send information through POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 1):

Form submit is when you want to submit the user defined values to the server . here in your example

```
<form class="delete" action="/post/delete/id/1234.html" method="POST">
    <input type="submit value="delete this post"/>
</form>
```

in form submit you can enter you values that has to be submitted to the server for manipulation. Examples of when to use form submits are Login page. Registration page, ie when user defined values are to be submitted to the server

but in this example

```
<a class="delete" href="/post/delete/id/1234.html">delete this post</a>
```

you are not having a input interface for the user to enter values and submit to the server. These are used when you want to pass static values which are not user defined or mainly to redirect to another page.